# Why does decodeFile throw "not enough bytes" error?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Why does `decodeFile` from `Data.Binary` throw the error `*** Exception: demandInput: not enough bytes`, when using `decode` and `readFile` from `Data.ByteString.Lazy` works as expected?

A minimal example

```
module Testing where

import Data.Binary
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

x :: Map.Map Char Int
x = Map.fromList $ zip ['a'..'d'] [1,2,3,4]

main :: IO (Map.Map Char Int)
main = do
  encodeFile "testing" (encode x)
  r <- decodeFile "testing"
  print $ r == x
  return r

main2 :: IO (Map.Map Char Int)
main2 = do
  B.writeFile "testing2" (encode x)
  r <- fmap decode $ B.readFile "testing2"
  print $ r == x
  return r
```

I found this potentially relevant question: [Using Data.Binary.decodeFile, encountered error "demandInput: not enough bytes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522278/using-data-binary-decodefile-encountered-error-demandinput-not-enough-bytes) but it does not really answer my question, which is why using `decodeFile` doesn't work but `readFile` does.

The output I get:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Testing          ( testing.hs, interpreted )                                                                                                         
Ok, modules loaded: Testing.                                                                                                                                            
*Testing> main                                                                                                                                                          
*** Exception: demandInput: not enough bytes              

*Testing> main2                                                                                                                                                         
True                                                                                                                                                                    
fromList [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
encodeFile "testing" (encode x)
```

which means you're encoding `x` *twice*. Changing that to

```
encodeFile "testing" x
```

works as expected.